# AWS Cognito + API Gateway + Calling Cognito Token Endpoint

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

Noob question here (beginner in AWS services). I wanted to create an API Gateway between the AWS Cognito and the one that's going to call the Cognito Token Endpoint. Is there a way how to implement it using a CDK? It is used to cache the Access Token.

Comment: Could you please explain the use case a bit? Why exactly do u need API Gateway in front of cognito? For extra layer of caching?

Comment: Because getting every single time an access token from Cognito is a bit slow. So some of the transactions being handled are being dropped. I think adding the API Gateway in between will help to lessen the time in getting the token and lessen the dropped transactions. I was thinking of `App - API Gateway (that has caching) - Cognito`.

Comment: So an authenticated user using your app/client calls API GW with its refresh token (TTL months) to get a fresh access token (TTL hours) for the next session. What is the chance it will hit the cache layer? Every call will need to go to cognito, unless the client logic is broken and the access token is obtained too often/not cached by client

Comment: The thing is, the one that is calling the Cognito token endpoint is a Lambda Layer. It is for the Opentelemetry instrumented application. So everytime this app is invoked, the Lambda Layer will then call the Cognito token endpoint. But the Lambda Layer keeps on dropping the events before it can send the traces to the collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to use an API Gateway between Cognito and the caller. It is using an HTTP Proxy.

Here's the guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html

And for caching the tokens, this might help:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-caching-tokens.html

The caching is enabled only for the `GET` method by default. If you are trying to use other types of HTTP Methods, might try to override the stage settings for it.

Here's the guide:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#override-api-gateway-stage-cache-for-method-cache